# Binding values in two instances of directive to one factory

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to bind two different instances of a directive to one a factory. Basically what I want is to click one following button and have both update and vice-versa. I have been playing around with this in a plunkr (which is a bit of a mess at the moment). If anyone could have a look at it and see where I am going wrong that would be greatly appreciated. Any questions just ask. Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <peers-following-button></peers-following-button>
    <peers-following-button></peers-following-button>
  </body>

</html>
```

app.js:

```
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);



app.controller('peerFollowingButtonController', peerFollowingButtonController);
    /*@ngInject*/
    function peerFollowingButtonController($scope,PeersHandlerService) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.isFollowing = PeersHandlerService.peerInformation.isFollowing;
         vm.followButtonTheme = 'blue-grey';
         vm.followButtonText = 'Follow';
        vm.followPeer = function() {
          vm.isFollowing = !vm.isFollowing
        };

        vm.followButtonTheme = 'blue-grey';



        $scope.$watch(function() {
            return vm.isFollowing;
        }, function(newVal) {

            if(newVal == true || newVal == "true") {
                vm.followButtonTheme = 'green';
                vm.followButtonText = 'Following';
            } else {
                vm.followButtonTheme = 'blue-grey';
                vm.followButtonText = 'Follow';
            }
        });

    }

app.directive('peersFollowingButton', peerFollowingButton);
    /*@ngInject*/
    function peerFollowingButton() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<button id="peer-follow-toolbar" style="background-color:{{vm.followButtonTheme}}" class="right white-text" ng-click="vm.followPeer()"> {{vm.followButtonText}}</button>',
            scope:{
                peerUsername: '='
            },
            controller: 'peerFollowingButtonController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            bindToController:true
        };
    }


app.factory('PeersHandlerService', peersHandlerService);
    /*@ngInject*/
    function peersHandlerService($q) {
        var service = {
            peerInformation: {
              isFollowing:false
            }
        };

        return service;

    }
```

plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/dTZ5Y3qtvyd5RnkqyIfX?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot. I just removed the isolated scope from the following-button directive and it works. Sorry for time wasting.